# What happens when you add a version/hash to your service worker file?

Tags: service-worker, browser-cache

I think it is a bad idea to use cache busting for your service worker by adding a version string to its file name. This is never mentioned in any tutorial and I've never seen this method out there in the wild.

You should rather use the [`no-cache` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843970/service-worker-javascript-update-frequency-every-24-hours/38854905#38854905) and the [`max-age` field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41447837/2092322) in the response header for the service worker file.

But since I did not find a dedicated statement regarding this method I tried it out and it seems like if you change the service worker file it is hard to get rid of the old one. So I can see both files in the *sources* tab of the dev-tools.

[image: Sources: two SW files]

But you won't see the new service worker in the *application* tab immediately, so I'm not sure, what hinders the new SW to get in charge and what it is actually waiting for.

[image: New SW (renamed!) awaits installation]

Does anybody know, how browsers usually handle this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's some guidance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#avoid-url-change) suggesting why that should be avoided:

> #### Avoid changing the URL of your service worker script
>
> If you've [read my
>   post](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/) on
>   caching best practices, you may consider giving each version of your
>   service worker a unique URL. Don't do this! This is usually bad
>   practice for service workers, just update the script at its current
>   location.
>
> It can land you with a problem like this:
>
> 1. index.html registers sw-v1.js as a service worker.
> 2. sw-v1.js caches and serves index.html so it works offline-first.
> 3. You update index.html so it registers your new and shiny sw-v2.js.
>
> If you do the above, the user never gets sw-v2.js, because sw-v1.js is
>   serving the old version of index.html from its cache. You've put
>   yourself in a position where you need to update your service worker in
>   order to update your service worker. Ew.

Comment: This section says _sw-v1.js caches and serves index.html so it works offline-first._, but we could create a SW, which uses the _network first policy_ for the `index.html`. In this case we would not run into the deadlock, right?

Comment: Also I still would like to understand a bit better the difference in how browsers handle service worker files of the same and of different names. Or is the updating process actually the same?

Comment: Registering a SW file with a different name will trigger a SW update. Changing the contents of a SW file while keeping the same name will also trigger a SW update. It's much simpler to just keep the same name and change the contents of the file, and then you don't have to worry about whether `index.html` is cache- or network-first.

Comment: Although this may be some what off-topic, I think it's worth to mention that `.webmanifest` (or `manifest.json` files should (probably) also not be versioned: https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/446#issuecomment-351368893