# Two service workers at the same time

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'd like to use two service workers on my site: one to provide a classic offline cache (`/sw.js`) for my PWA and another for something like a local database "server" which uses background sync and push (`/sw-db.js`). Since the latter tends to do heavy work (blocking the event loop for a few ms) it's better to keep it separate.

Since the database sw is not used for fetch requests, I would give it a dummy scope, whereas `sw.js` is scoped for the whole domain.

Does the first, which responds to "fetch" events, also serve the code/URL for `/sw-db.js` (keeping it *somewhat* in-sync with site updates) or are service workers *always* updated via network.

Answer (score 1):

The `sw.js` script URL that you pass in to `navigatior.serviceWorker.register('/path/to/sw.js')` will always be fetched bypassing any other service workers when it's time to check for updates. So to answer your question, the other service worker's `fetch` handler won't be triggered.

The [HTTP cache does come into play](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38854905/385997) whenever there's an update check for a service worker script. So you should make sure you're setting proper HTTP cache control headers for your use case.

Usually, a service worker update check is triggered due to a navigation to a page controlled by a service worker, but if you have a service worker with a "dummy" scope, it won't end up controlling any pages. That being said, when a service worker handlers `sync` or `push` events you'll also end up triggering the update check. I'm not sure if every `sync` or `push` triggers the check, or just a subset of them, such as the ones which cause a new service worker to spawn. But it will happen at least some of the time.