# Is it possible to multiple service workers run at the same time and handle different or same event types?

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push, service-worker-events

There is a lot of information over the internet and also here on Stackoverflow, but I'm still confused and be glad to get some clarifications.
I have read:

- [How to register two different service-workers in the same scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651305/how-to-register-two-different-service-workers-in-the-same-scope)
- [Two service workers at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758968/two-service-workers-at-the-same-time)
- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/service-worker-lifecycle
- https://web.dev/articles/service-worker-mindset
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

and more (including Firebase docs, MDN docs).

My questions are:

**What happens when I register 2 service workers for the same scope?**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw1.js', {scope: '/'})
            .then(registration => {
                console.log('sw1 registered with scope:', registration.scope);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('sw2 registration failed:', error);
            });
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw2.js', {scope: '/'})
            .then(registration => {
                console.log('sw2 registered with scope:', registration.scope);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('sw2 registration failed:', error);
            });
    }
```

Lets call them `sw1.js`:

```
self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
```

and `sw2.js`:

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
```

I understand that the last one that got registered is the one that becomes active and take charge of the scope. So - does it mean the first one, `sw1` has no "power" at all?

Let me explain: if `sw1` handles `push` events while `sw2` handles `onclickNotifications` events, and `sw2` is registered after `sw1`, does it mean that when a `push` event will be received, nothing will be handled since `sw2` is now in charge and has no logic of handling `push` events?

Is there any `event bubbling` that "passes" the event to the other service worker in case it's not handled in the first one?

**In case the answer is yes**, that there is sort of "event bubbling" that passes the event to the other service worker if event handling is missing, can you "skip" an event by purpose in case you don't want to handle it in `sw1` so it will be handled in `sw2`?

What I mean is if both service workers handle the same event types, lets say `push` events, but I want `sw1` handle only `push` events that contain the title "Oh, Hi Mark", can I "skip" it so it will be handled by `sw2`?