# How to handle Cache in .htaccess file when using a Service Worker

Tags: .htaccess, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, auto-update

I'm coding a PWA for the first time and wonder if my `.htaccess` cache policy isn't about to conflict with my Service Worker Stategies. Here is how it looks in my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 days"
</IfModule>
```

Should I remove that part in order to make my Service Worker handle cache properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thea meaning of "conflict" is not very clear here. It depends completely on what you mean by that. With 99.99 % certainty there's no "conflict" of any kind, these are inherently separate technologies that don't step on each others' toes. Be aware that Service Worker is a scriptable interface so there's no single Service Worker. Your SW could do something completely different than mine.

It is good to remember that caches work like this:

Without Service Worker:
Browser <--> Browser's HTTP cache (HTTP headers) <--> HTTP Server

With Service Worker:
Browser <--> Service Worker <--> Browser's HTTP cache (HTTP headers) <--> HTTP Server

Now, in your case, the .htaccess is the thing that attaches HTTP caching headers to the responses served by your HTTP server. So those caching headers will be seen by the Service Worker when it contacts the HTTP server. They're not "conflicting". They're not an "either/or" type of a situation. They're doing different things.

Example:

1. Server has app.css
2. Browser asks for app.css
3. Service Worker sees the request for app.css
4. Service Worker sends the request to the HTTP server
5. Request goes through browser's HTTP interface and cache
6. HTTP server responds with app.css and says: "Cache this for one month!"
7. Response comes back through browser's HTTP interface and is saved in the HTTP cache
8. Service Worker *maybe does something* with the response
9. Service Worker forwards the response back to the browser
10. Browser now has app.css

Point 8: at this point *usually* the SW caches the response in the Cache API (this is separate, not HTTP cache).
Point 3: at this point *usually* the SW checks the Cache API to see whether the request has already been cached (if above has happened). If Cache API provides the answer, SW skips steps 4–8 and just responds with the cached version.

But, because the Serwice Worker is scriptable, it might be doing something different.

I REALLY RECOMMEND you read this blog post about different HTTP caching schemes and how they work with Service Worker: https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

### Turn off `.htaccess` directed caching for `service-worker.js`

One can completely turn off server instructed browser caching for the `service-worker.js` of the progressive web app (PWA), [as explained here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/turning-off-caching-using-htaccess).

Simply place the following hidden `.htaccess` file in the server directory containing the `service-worker.js`:

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|js)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

This will disable caching for all `.js` and `.html` files in this server directory and those below; which is more than `service-worker.js` alone.

Only these two file types were selected because these are the non-static files of my PWA that may **affect users who are running the app in a browser window** without installing it (yet) as a full-fledged automatically updating PWA.