# Service Worker in root on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, service-worker

I am trying to use a service worker on a basic flask app on Google App Engine for Python. From what I understand if I want the service worker to handle all requests on my domain it needs to be in the application root. However I can't figure out how to let GAE allow access to my service-worker.js in the root. I currently get a 404 response when trying to register the service worker. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this via the `static_files` option in your `app.yaml`, as [described in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers).

You should probably [opt your `/service-worker.js` out of caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843970/service-worker-javascript-update-frequency-every-24-hours/38854905#38854905) at the same time.

Something like:

```
handlers:
- url: /service-worker\.js
  static_files: service-worker.js
  upload: service-worker\.js
  expiration: 0m
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but I also had to make sure my catch all handler `url: ./*` came after the service-worker url handler.

Comment: this solution works for me when i run it locally, but does not work after deploying (i'm getting 404). any idea why?