# sw-precache not updating and taking only cached data

Tags: caching, progressive-web-apps, sw-precache

Iam trying to implement **networkfirst** strategy using **sw-precache**.
Now iam able to cache the data and able to serve from **offline**. If i change the data (i.e: changed the header from 'hello' to 'Welcome') in page not get reflecting it always taking the data from the cache its getting update only if i unregistered the service worker or clear the site data then only i can get my data

**Here is my sw-precache gulp task :**

```
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', function(callback) {
  var path = require('path');
  var swPrecache = require('sw-precache');
  var rootDir = '.';

  swPrecache.write(path.join(rootDir, 'sw.js'), {
    staticFileGlobs: [
      rootDir + '/css/**.css',
      rootDir + '/js/**/*.{js,css}',
      rootDir + '/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
      rootDir + '/*.{html,js}',
    ],
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: 'http://localhost:8080',
        handler: 'networkFirst'
      }],
    stripPrefix: rootDir
  }, callback); 
});
```

Comment: Have you seen the [Service Worker Precache docs](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache) ?

Comment: @noogui yes, Is there is any mistake i have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check:

- Ensure that you're not caching your `sw.js` file, as this could delay updates for up to 24 hours in Chrome. ([Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843970/service-worker-javascript-update-frequency-every-24-hours/38854905#38854905).)
- You're checking for updating content on the *subsequent* visit to the site following your update? Because of the cache-first strategy, the initial visit to the site following the update won't show the new content (because the cache has been updated "in the background").

Comment: I modified the gulp file to cache sw.js,but I couldn't  able to cache sw.js ,  even though i use network first i am having the same problem

Comment: I meant that you should **not** cache `sw.js` via `Cache-Control` headers. See the SO answer I linked to for more details.

Comment: Oh sorry @Jeff for misunderstanding now i checked the cache memory and  i didn't cache the "sw.js" i getting my page update  if I checked the update on reloading  in dom  or clear the cache else i could not get updated content

Comment: Could you share the URL for your deployed site?

Comment: I am checking it in local machine only

Comment: could you please help to get out this problem

Comment: I don't have any specific suggestions in general beyond what I've already made. If you could deploy this somewhere public, that would help debug, but without access to your web app there's not much more that I could contribute.

Comment: I took a look at https://pwa.vamsoft.in/sw.js and you're not in face using `sw-precache`, as you mentioned in your original question. Have you changed your site since originally asking?

Comment: Yes If I changed the HTML contents in the home page then the old one is getting shown unless until I unregister the service worker and reload the page

Comment: My point is that you asked a question about `sw-precache`, but you're not actually using it.

Comment: Apologies for that, Kindly check it now.

Comment: I took a look at your site—given that you're preaching your `/` URL via `sw-precache`, it's going to be served in a cache-first strategy (`sw-precache` does everything cache-first). That means that you won't see updated until the *next* visit to the site following a deployment. This is the expected behavior, and if you want different behavior, you need to exclude your HTML from being precached.

Comment: And also tell which is the best way to cache HTML pages

Comment: @jeffPosnik kindly share the above prerequisite a have asked

Comment: The comments thread of a previously answered Stack Overflow question is not the best place to ask for follow-ups. Could you please ask a new question with details of what you're looking for?

Comment: @JeffPosnick BTW if you exclude index.html from being cached, then offline mode will not work. Right? What is the solution for this?

Comment: @JeffPosnick kindly help my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586398/pwa-add-to-home-screen-not-showing-popup?noredirect=1#comment90156355_51586398