# Is it possible for a hybrid app to convert into a PWA?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Looking forward to know if it's possible to turn a hybrid app into a PWA?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. I've made one with *Angular* so if you have any more questions feel free to ask.

**Angular PWA**

Here are the details https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/pwa

The `@angular/pwa` package will automatically add a service worker and an [app manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) to the app. To add this package to the app, run:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

**React PWA**

Here are the details https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/pwa

---

**Additional links**:

- [PWA add to home screen not showing a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586398/pwa-add-to-home-screen-not-showing-popup)