# Update Workbox controlled pre-cached items in "installed" (added to home screen) PWA

Tags: offline, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using Workbox 2 to deal with "offline" behavior of my PWA. The content is produced by [HexoJS](https://hexo.io/) and is deployed to GitHub Pages. Here is the `workbox-cli-config.js` for reference:

```js
module.exports = {
    globDirectory: "./public/",
    globPatterns: ["**/*.html", "**/*.js", "**/*.css", "**/*.png"],
    swDest: "public/sw.js",
    clientsClaim: true,
    skipWaiting: true,
    runtimeCaching: [
        {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/use\.fontawesome\.com\/releases/,
            handler: "networkFirst"
        },
        {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com\/s\//,
            handler: "networkFirst"
        },
        {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/maxcdn\.bootstrapcdn\.com\/bootstrap/,
            handler: "networkFirst"
        },
        {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com/,
            handler: "networkFirst"
        },
        {
            urlPattern: /^https:\/\/code\.jquery\.com\/jquery-3/,
            handler: "networkFirst"
        },
    ]
};
```

Everything works as expected and the app properly handles switch to the offline mode in Chrome DevTools.

The **problem** shows up when I update some static content, say HTML, and re-deploy it onto the GitHub pages  --- I can see the updated version of the content but **not always**, and **not in all browsers**.

I always have to use "Clear browsing data" action in Opera or Chrome (or other browsers) to refresh the appearance of the page, because simple "Refresh/reload" doesn't help.

The problem gets even worser with the "Added to home screen" PWA. I cannot enforce content refresh even by doing uninstall/reinstall. Only wiping off browsing data in Android Chrome browser helps to refresh app content.

My **questions** are:

- Is it possible at all to let pre-cached static assets being automatically updated when I re-visit the page or refresh the installed PWA?
- Am I configuring Workbox in a wrong way (see my `workbox-cli-config.js` above)
- Will migration to Workbox 3 make any difference?

I'd be glad to share other config files if this will help to resolve to problem.

**PS**: The page has the **score of 100 in Lighthouse** for all criteria except for performance (because of loading blocking content of `bootstrap.min.js` but read in SO that this is OK).

Comment: It's very likely that you're running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843970/service-worker-javascript-update-frequency-every-24-hours/38854905#38854905, because GitHub pages always includes a `Cache-Control: max-age=600` header on all its HTTP responses.

Comment: I totally forgot to mention that I pass site GitHub Pages traffic through Cloudflare to allow HTTPs on custom domain. After reading the first comment I looked at HTTP header and noticed the `max-age=14400` for my service-worker script, so I guess it was heavily cached by Cloudflare without leaving my PWA any chances for static content refreshing.

I added `Cache Level: bypass` page rule on Cloudflare specifically for `sw.js`, and now I can see `max-age=600` enforced by GitHub pages.