# Angular ServiceWorkers + MIME type error

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to add service workers to our existing angular (5.2, CLI 1.7.1) application. I did everything I was suppose to:

1. I created *ngsw-config.json*
2. I run the the `ng set apps.0.serviceWorker=true` command so I have `"serviceWorker": true,` in *angular-cli.json*.
3. I have installed `"@angular/service-worker": "5.2.9"`
4. I added to *app.module.ts*:

   ```
   import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
   imports: [
       ...
       ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', 
           { enabled: environment.production }),
   ]
   ```

I even tried to add this piece of code (which I found as a solution somewhere) to main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
    }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**But I got this error:**

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a
>   ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
>
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to register
>   a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type
>   ('text/html'). at resolvePromise
>   (polyfills.3e9ea997ddae46e16c09.bundle.js:1)

In my own personal small app, I did the same and it worked without any errors. The application where we have this error is pretty huge. With a lot of third party libraries. I've read that there can be a problem with them.

Can you help me please?

**Also, I was checking my own application to find possible differences, which I didn't but I looked at network tab in devtools and I've noticed that the files which should be cached by service worker are always loaded. Is it a correct behaviour please?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is probably caused by a missing ngsw-worker.js file.

Likely you are using [HTML5 pushState style URLs](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles), and you have [configured your web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833154/1408642) to return your index page (typically index.html) for any file or folder that does not physically exist on the server. If ngsw-worker.js does not physically exist, the web server will redirect a request to ngsw-worker.js to index.html (hence the MIME type "text/html").

The ngsw-worker.js file is typically copied to your dist folder when you run

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it out and if it works I'll mark you :) If I may, how should it look in networks tab (devtools) when it works properly? Should there be any download of "cached" files? Or should it be instantaneous?

Comment: You'll see a 200 OK. The file may be served from cache if it is was successfully loaded previously. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843970/service-worker-javascript-update-frequency-every-24-hours/38854905#38854905 for more about the caching of that particular file.

Comment: ng build --prod solves the problem. How to run ng build --prod but using development environment.ts?

Comment: For Angular 5 and older, add an entry to the "environments" property in the "production" configuration in angular-cli.json. Then, run "ng build --prod --env=foo". For Angular 6+, either remove the environment.ts entry from the "fileReplacements" property in the "production" configuration in angular.json, or copy the configuration and modify as required. Then, run "ng run yourproject:build:foo".

Comment: or you can enable "serviceWorker": true in your configuration (angular.json)

Comment: thanks! worked for me, angular 8...removed --base-href in build command

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of different things with Angular8 I finally upgraded angular-devkit from 0.800.2 to 0.803.2

`npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest`

Then I got an error:

Error: Expected to find an ngsw-config.json configuration file in the [PROJECT] folder. Either provide one or disable Service Worker in your angular.json configuration file.

I fixed this by changing

`"ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"`
to
`"ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json"`

Then it finally worked.