# ionic/angular pwa doesn't bootstrap when launched from home screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, progressive-web-apps

I followed these guides to add pwa support and host my ionic v4 app:

- https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-pwa-with-angular-service-workers-in-ionic-4/
- https://www.joshmorony.com/hosting-an-ionic-pwa-with-firebase-hosting/

The app loads fine in Safari, and I can also add the app to my home screen (ios).  However, from the home screen, the app does not bootstrap when launched.

If I go to Safari DevTools and reload the page after launch, the app is just fine.

I'm also not exactly clear on the minimum requirements for a `pwa`. My app loads the `google maps javascript api` on launch, so it doesn't really work without a network connection. I'm not sure if that is part of the problem or not.

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.3.1 (/Users/m/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.15
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.7
   @angular/cli                  : 7.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.1.0

Capacitor:

   capacitor (Capacitor CLI) : 1.0.0-beta.7
   @capacitor/core           : 1.0.0-beta.7

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 2.0.0
   NodeJS     : v8.9.4 (/Users/m/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```

on reload of the pwa app from DevTools, I see this error:

```
[Error] ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: MIME Type is not a JavaScript MIME type
    vt (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:123807)
    handleError (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:124014)
    next (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:139466)
    (anonymous function) (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:131304)
    __tryOrUnsub (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:247187)
    next (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:246340)
    _next (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:245384)
    next (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:245056)
    next (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:272048)
    emit (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:131085)
    run (polyfills.0548e3ebf74d8c45f01b.js:1:2461)
    onHandleError (main.0c301dd161ca4cc6d73d.js:1:133065)
    runGuarded (polyfills.0548e3ebf74d8c45f01b.js:1:2721)
    e (polyfills.0548e3ebf74d8c45f01b.js:1:11589)
    microtaskDrainDone (polyfills.0548e3ebf74d8c45f01b.js:1:11638)
    d (polyfills.0548e3ebf74d8c45f01b.js:1:10261)
    promiseReactionJob
```

It seems like it should be related to [Angular ServiceWorkers + MIME type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476329/angular-serviceworkers-mime-type-error), but I'm using `ionic build --prod; firebase deploy` and the build output is all minimized.

Here's the network log when I launch the App from Home screen:

[image: Network log when App is launched from home screen]

And here's what it looks like after I click reload in DevTools

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this as a workaround for now:

```
  async patch_PWA_bootstrap(){
    const RELOAD_LIMIT = 5000
    const el = document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0];
    const now = Date.now();
    if (el.classList.contains('plt-pwa')){
      const resp = await Storage.get({key:'PWA_RELOAD'});
      if ( now - JSON.parse(resp.value) < RELOAD_LIMIT) 
        return;  // wait at  before next reload

      const cancel = setTimeout( async ()=>{
        // something not bootstrapping correctly with pwa.  reload() fixes
        await Storage.set({key:'PWA_RELOAD', value:JSON.stringify(now)});
        window.location.reload();
      },100)
    }
  }
```

I'm calling it when the PWA app loads and when it returns to foreground