# Ionic 3 PWA: How to force JavaScript refresh?

Tags: version, updates, progressive-web-apps, ionic3

I'm developing a PWA using Ionic 3. I need to make browser to update the PWA version, but it not always happens when I upload a new version to the server.

How  could I force the update of the PWA version in user's browser?

Comment: Hi. I have the same issue. Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: Basically you guys want to learn something like this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262385/service-worker-force-update-of-new-assets?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa