# Reactjs service worker in a Web Application

Tags: reactjs, browser, service-worker

I am new to web app development so pardon my questions.

I just noticed that a web app I created using create-react-app that has service worker installed, upload it to my server, won't reload the new app after being built when I open it from my local Chrome browser, even though I reload node on my server many times, and hard reload Chrome browser.

I removed the service worker from my app and now Chrome always get the new app.

How do I 'force' service worker to update itself in my app so I always get the new build app every time I push it to my server?

If I have to add this `Cache-Control: no-cache` or other cache mechanism https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control what's the use of service worker then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution would disallow installing Service worker if in Dev mode. For your development workflow, you always want your new code without the caching side-effects of service-workers. You can do this by doing something like -

```
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === "PRODUCTION") {
  // service worker init code
}
```

Also make sure to set NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION or NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT for your respective prod and dev scripts.

Hope this helps!

**Updates**

A few project to help you with the sw lifecycle -

1. [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox)
2. [offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin)

Comment: Yeah I do that. Sorry maybe my explanation isn't clear. When I build and deploy it to my production server, the internet, it still show the outdated app. That's why I have to remove the service worker from my code so it shows the latest app.

Comment: Hey Eko! Do take a look at this answer on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262385/service-worker-force-update-of-new-assets. I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't answer my question but clears my confusion of how to use service worker with the best practice possible.